# How to have different sliding styles for desktop and mobile using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like have top to bottom sliding for web view and left to right sliding for mobile view with bootstrap how can I do this, Is bootstrap have options for enabling mobile view so that we can display something specific when website is being viewed with mobile

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is include 2 headers. One for mobile (visible-xs) and one tablet / desktop (hidden-xs) class.

```
<div class="jumbotron top-bottom-animation visible-xs">
This is visible only for mobile phones
</div>

<div class="jumbotron left-right-animation hidden-xs">
This is vissible for all other devices
</div>
```

You should apply your animation with the device.